# Overriding Camel & log4j

Tags: java, logging, log4j, apache-camel

I'm fairly new to Apache Camel, but have to say that I love it so far. One "limitation" (probably a lack of understanding on my part) I've hit so far is that Camel ships with `log4j` as its default logging component.

My team has already gone to great lengths to build our own logging framework, which ends up posting all log messages to an ActiveMQ queue, and ultimately, our database.

I'd like to configure Camel to work with our logging framework, since so much has already been invested in getting it working. Although Camel doesn't seem to provide any documentation on this, I do have two ideas and wanted to run them by the SO community.

(1) Find a way to re-configure `log4j`'s LoggerFactory. That way we can have our own LoggerFactory return instances of our homegrown Loggers.

(2) Write our own `log4j` appender, which would use our homegrown Logger.

Has anyone ever had experience with this? Is there an easier/better/more elegant solution out there? Any input is appreciated.

Comment: Camel uses commons-logging in Camel 2.6.x or older. From Camel 2.7.0 onwards we use slf4j. So you can pick and chose which log kit you want to use. You are not forced to use log4j.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log4J already provides a JMSAppender. You could be able to just configure one and go. Check out http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-use-log4j-jms-appender-with-activemq.html